# Can't create database from coding but can from cpanel

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel

The database **test_new_1** is able to create for the user **testcom** directly from the cpanel, But not able to create through php. Another server it is working properly, the only difference username and database prefix is same in that server.

**Error Shows:**

```
Error creating database: Access denied for user 'testcom'@'localhost' to database 'test_new_1'
```

**PHP**

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'testcom', '123456');
// Check connection
if (!$conn)
{
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_new_1";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
echo "Database created successfully";
}
else
{
echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: In that case, it should not allow to create from cpanel also. But here can create from cpanel.

Comment: grant access to user testcom

Comment: Gave access, then all other projects databases shown in this user phpmyadmin, I have tried grant wildcard which not executed shows error.

Answer (score 4):

cPanel does not allow you to create databases directly from with MySQL function. You need to use the API provided to you by cPanel:

Download `xmlapi.php` from https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php then use it:

```
<?php
    include("xmlapi.php");

    $db_host = 'yourdomain.com'; 
    $cpaneluser = 'your cpanel username';
    $cpanelpass = 'your cpanel password'; 

    $databasename = 'testdb';
    $databaseuser = 'test'; // Warning: in most of cases this can't be longer than 8 characters
    $databasepass = 'dbpass'; // Warning: be sure the password is strong enough, else the CPanel will reject it

    $xmlapi = new xmlapi($db_host);    
    $xmlapi->password_auth("".$cpaneluser."","".$cpanelpass."");    
    $xmlapi->set_port(2082);
    $xmlapi->set_debug(1);//output actions in the error log 1 for true and 0 false  
    $xmlapi->set_output('array');//set this for browser output  
    //create database    
    $createdb = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adddb", array($databasename));   
    //create user 
    $usr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduser", array($databaseuser, $databasepass));   
     //add user 
    $addusr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduserdb", array("".$cpaneluser."_".$databasename."", "".$cpaneluser."_".$databaseuser."", 'all'));
?>
```